# Excel FIle Generated from SSIS cannot be accessed. the file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read only

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a requirement in which i need to send the ETL data report with actual added, updated and deleted records in a excel.

Excel will be having 3 sheets. ie: Inserted, Updated and Deleted.

Im able to create required sheets in the Excel file and through execute SQL tasks.

[image]

Once the tabs are created, im even able to push the data into the respective sheets.
the file generation is successful as i expect. But, the problem is while opening the file. I get an error as shown below.

Excel FIle Generated from SSIS cannot be accessed. the file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read only.

Comment: The images are missing on this question @Vikram

Comment: Im sorry. not able to upload more than 2 images.

Comment: Maybe try the most useful 2 images to explain your question- currently none are working.

Comment: @VikramD See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for instructions on images

Comment: My life is complete